# Python jira 401 recoverable error using basic auth

Tags: python, jira

I am using python jira client to establish a connection to jira using basic auth.

```
from jira.client import JIRA

jira = JIRA(options={'server': 'https://server.atlassian.net'},
            basic_auth=('email@example.com', 'pass'))
```

This code worked fine till yesterday.

> Got recoverable error from GET https://server.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/serverInfo, will retry [1/3] in 17.5832343958s. Err: 401

My password and email is correct. I am able to login manually

Comment: Something has to have changed.  I doubt that Atlassian changed something to prevent access because your request is coming from code, or something like that.  if that's not it, then it seems that it has to be something on your side...your code, your workstation, your network...something.  The code speaks for itself, and you also say it worked until recently.  I think all anyone reading this on S.O. can do is make wild guesses as to what's going on.

Answer (score 6):

Basic authentication with passwords and cookie-based authentication no longer work since effectively 14 April 2019 for Jira and Confluence cloud - see [deprecation notice](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/deprecation-notice-basic-auth-and-cookie-based-auth/). [Api token](https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/api-tokens-938839638.html) needs to be used in place of passwords for `basic_auth`.

This snippet below should work:

```
from jira.client import JIRA

api_token = "***********************"
jira = JIRA(options={'server': 'https://server.atlassian.net'},
        basic_auth=('email@example.com', api_token))
```

I've also raised an issue in `pycontrib/jira` to reflect this: https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/issues/780.

Jira tickets to follow:

- https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/ACJIRA-1465
- https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/ACJIRA-1466

Answer (score 0):

Strange, might be security settings with HTTP vs HTTPS.  Try passing to https instead of http.

> from jira.client import JIRA
>
> jira = JIRA(options={'server': 'https://server.atlassian.net'},
>              basic_auth=('email@example.com', 'pass'))

Answer (score 0):

It seems like passwords are being deprecated for the REST API. Perhaps this would help further: [Atlassian Authentication](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/deprecation-notice-basic-auth-and-cookie-based-auth/)